# Where to declare an object literal inside of a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object

i have a UI class & i want to declare UISelectors object inside of it, where do i put it?

```
export default class UI{
    constructor(){
    }
    // it works here but i don't know if it should be inside of the constructor 
    //or what is the best practice for this 
    UISelectors = {
        itemList: '#item-list',
        listItems: '#item-list li',
        addBtn: '.add-btn'
    }
    populateItemList(items){
        let html = '';
        items.forEach(function(item){
            html += `<li class="collection-item" id="item-${item.id}">
            <strong>${item.name}: </strong> <em>${item.calories} Calories</em>
            <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
              <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>
          </li>`
        })
        document.querySelector(this.UISelectors.itemList).innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

is it wrong to declare variables and objects inside of a class? or how should i do it.

Comment: well should it be a property of the class?

Comment: i am really new into this, but to be more clear variables/objects i want to use inside of a class should be properties of the class like shown in my code? or should be declared somehow else?

Comment: It really depends on the code.

Comment: Looks like field declarations outside class methods are experimental so it would be safer to put it inside constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations

Comment: @gp. so data i want to use (variables, object literal, arrays, etc ..)in a class should be inside of the constructor not as a class property correct?

Comment: Correct until declarations at class level is supported by the browsers you want to target.

Comment: for anyone wondering, i figured out that i should use data outside of the constructor and use static keyword before it, in order that data doesn't show in the instantiated objects.

Answer (score 0):

today 2022 and you can declare any static or public fields with any data in your class